# Are RTCDataChannels guaranteed to open after the ICE state becomes connected?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

During high CPU load, in Firefox, an RTCDataChannel's `onopen` event fires before the RTCPeerConnection's `oniceconnectionstatechange`. I'm wondering if there is anything in the spec regarding the order in which the two events fire, and how to ensure that `oniceconnectionstatechange` fires first.

```
              | Chrome 88                         | Firefox 85
--------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------
Low CPU load  | oniceconnectionstatechange first  | oniceconnectionstatechange first
              | onopen second                     | onopen second
--------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------
High CPU load | oniceconnectionstatechange first  | onopen first?
              | onopen second                     | oniceconnectionstatechange second
```

This is the code I'm using to test:

```
(async function()
{
    var p1 = new RTCPeerConnection();
    var p2 = new RTCPeerConnection();
    
    p1.channel = p1.createDataChannel("channel", { negotiated: true, id: 88 });
    p2.channel = p2.createDataChannel("channel", { negotiated: true, id: 88 });
    
    p1.onicecandidate = function(e)
    {
        if(e.candidate)
            p2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
    };
    
    p2.onicecandidate = function(e)
    {
        if(e.candidate)
            p1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
    };
    
    p1.oniceconnectionstatechange = function()
    {
        if(p1.iceConnectionState === "connected")
            console.log("P1 PeerConnection connected");
    };
    
    p2.oniceconnectionstatechange = function()
    {
        if(p2.iceConnectionState === "connected")
            console.log("P2 PeerConnection connected");
    };
    
    p1.channel.onopen = function()
    {
        console.log("P1 DataChannel opened");
    };
    
    p2.channel.onopen = function()
    {
        console.log("P2 DataChannel opened");
    };
    
    var offer = await p1.createOffer();
    await p1.setLocalDescription(offer);
    await p2.setRemoteDescription(offer);
    
    var answer = await p2.createAnswer();
    await p2.setLocalDescription(answer);
    await p1.setRemoteDescription(answer);
})();

//create some load
requestAnimationFrame(renderingLoopTest); //comment this line for no load
function renderingLoopTest()
{
    var lag = Date.now();
    while(Date.now() - lag < 60);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderingLoopTest);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for discovering this! Would you mind filing a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=WebRTC) on Firefox? I'll write an answer later, but in the meantime see [w3c/webrtc-pc#2622](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/2622).

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1691222